# How to sort a concatenated field in MS-Access 2013 Query

Tags: sorting, ms-access, concatenation, ms-query

I have two concatenated fields in a ms-access query,
The fields are: [FirstName] & " " & [LastName], and I want to sort them by last name.
How do I sort them like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the [LastName] field in your query (but not shown) and then click the Sort drop-down and select Ascending (or Descending, if you like).  Then sort on the [FirstName] or on the concatenated field.  The order in which the sort is performed is left to right, in terms of the fields in the query builder, so you'd need to drag/drop appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, there is actually no need to sort the concatenated field, all I did was, add the last name field again separately, and sort it while not shown, whicht effected the concatenated fields sorting automatically.

Comment: Yep yep - sounds reasonable.  Glad I could help!